# Support For The Pug Template Engine In Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, pug, pugjs

With Jade transitioning to Pug, There currently isn't a Pug plugin.
The problem is that our .jade file extension becomes .pug which isn't recognized by the IDE.

How can we use pug with Intellij IDEA (or other Intellij IDEs)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until the Intellij Jade plugin becomes the Pug plugin, a workaround to using Pug is to recognize .pug files as Jade files.

This can be done by:

Opening Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> File Types

Find Jade under Recognized File Types

Add *.pug to the list of Registered Patterns